# Changing the column header font size in a DataGrid via code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, header

I would like to change font size of the header of a datagrid by code (C#).
I don't have any idea how to do it. Searched around for lets say two hours without any success.
In XAML (via style and setter) I know how to do it but I have to change the font size by code.

Any ideas? Would be great ...

Comment: You stated that you know how to change it in XAML using style. Where you changed it in XAML then name the element (x:name) and and refer to the element name style property in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just apply a new style in code, almost everything that can be done in XAML can be translated.

Comment: @BalamBalam: Are you trying to assign a `string` to a property of type `Style` or what? Of course tha would not work.

Comment: But how? What is the property of the DataGrid I have to change?
DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle I suppose? But what then?

Comment: @manton: Just create a style that has a setter for the font-size in code and assign that to said property.

Comment: Thanks - that will work. It was of course a simple question - I'm a beginner but nevertheless thank you.

Answer (score 0):

well loop through your columns, get their Column.Header, convert it (cast) to ColumnHeader then change the FontSize of this column header. you might use Tag property to know which column is which (or Name)